# Css responsive color change

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build my first website which is a clone like to spotify landing page everything is alright when the page is classic desktop size but when I can change the screen size it differenties the color of the background.

that's the code ;

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,700');

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(234.43deg, #1C6652 23.77%, rgba(157, 117, 207, 0.352343) 71.57%,
   rgba(106, 130, 251, 0) 99.57%);;
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: white;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.full-height-grow {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column ;
  

}
```

[color problem at different screen size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9sNd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gradient-stops seem to be causing the problem. You can either remove the stops for the mobile screen sizes or you can play with the gradient angle.

Comment: sorry I did not catch the "gradient-stops" can u explain a little bit detailed

Comment: You used `linear-gradient(234.43deg, #1C6652 23.77%, rgba(157, 117, 207, 0.352343) 71.57%,
   rgba(106, 130, 251, 0) 99.57%)`

the 23.77%, 71.57% and 99.57% - aren't they gradient stops?

Comment: I forgot to thank you thanks again.